# Laravel Post to Facebook With My Own Web

Tags: php, facebook, laravel

I want to post an article from other website,

from my laravel project,

to facebook post,

with my website link.

I can post an article from other source to facebook, and it's show like the image below, but one thing that i want to add is "MY WEB LINK"

like "via www.MYWEB.com" or "www.MYWEB.com"

[image: sample image]

How to do this with laravel code?

Comment: You can get some help here: https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @AlankarMore I create facebook developer to make a post on facebook, but i can't connect it to my laravel

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you have to do here.

1. You need to authorise with Facebook via your Facebook application. One of the packages that can help you greatly to do that is [Laravel Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite).
2. You will need the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) to interact with Facebook APIs.